# How can I use device gestures in Oracle MAF application?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, oracle-maf

I want to use phone shake gesture in my oracle mobile app. I found an artical related to Oracle MAF device gestures here:

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/ADFMobileDesign/Pattern+-+Device+Gestures

But didn't found any example that how can we use this in mobile app. If anyone has implemented this before, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a custom cordova shake plugin to my MAF application and invoke it from javascript file which was included on application home page feature. You can get cordova plugin and its usage techniques from here:

https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake

Answer (score 0):

This video helped me use the Swype in my application :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbFwiXSayUM

add tag to view tag:

```
<amx:view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amx="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx"
      xmlns:dvtm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/mf/amx/dvt">
<amx:navigationDragBehavior action="volver" direction="back" id="ndb1"/>
```

and add action on navigation action on taskflow

```
<control-flow-case id="__4">
        <from-outcome>volverInicio</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>taskFlowReturn1</to-activity-id>
        <transition>slideRight</transition>
      </control-flow-case>
```